# XHR.send error in Firefox 7/8 but not FF6/Chrome: 0x80460001 (NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA)

Tags: file, encoding, upload, send, xmlhttprequest

i'm having problems with a drag and drop file upload script in firefox 7/8. i have written a basic script to upload files dropped into the dropzone of the html document to a server-side script "save.php". the full html including the javascript can be found below. the server-side part is not a problem and therefore i left it out (save.php).

i searched and tried everything but now i'm really stuck. the script runs in firefox 6 and also in chrome without any javascript error when i drop a file to upload (furthermore, the file is correctly saved on the server calling save.php). 
but in ff7/8 i get the following error in the firebug console when i drop a file on the dropzone to upload:

Component returned failure code: 0x80460001 (NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA)
this.send(ui8a.buffer);   newfu.html (Line 105)

can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong? is this a bug of firefox 7/8? then why does it work in chrome AND firefox 6?

is the string i send in xhr.send() not correctly encoded?

thanks a lot for any help!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>cross browser drag and drop file upload example</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // add the dataTransfer property for use with the native `drop` event
    // to capture information about files dropped into the browser window
    jQuery.event.props.push("dataTransfer");

    $(function() {
        $('#dropzone').bind("drop",function(evnt) {
            evnt.stopPropagation();
            evnt.preventDefault();

            var data = evnt.dataTransfer;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                var file = data.files[i];


                var boundary = '------multipartformboundary' + (new Date).getTime();
                var dashdash = '--';
                var crlf     = '\r\n';

                // Build RFC2388 string
                var builder = '';
                var builder2 = '';

                builder += dashdash;
                builder += boundary;
                builder += crlf;

                // generate headers            
                builder += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_file[]"';
                if (file.fileName) {
                  builder += '; filename="' + file.fileName + '"';
                }
                builder += crlf;

                builder += 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream';
                builder += crlf;
                builder += crlf; 

                //
                // binary data string in FileReader's onload (see below)
                //

                builder2 += crlf;

                //write boundary
                builder2 += dashdash;
                builder2 += boundary;
                builder2 += crlf;

                // mark end of the request
                builder2 += dashdash;
                builder2 += boundary;
                builder2 += dashdash;
                builder2 += crlf;


                // setup filereader: read file and send it
                reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(evt) {
                    binary = evt.target.result;

                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("POST", "save.php", true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);

                    //sendAsBinary: deprecated Mozilla only, define NEWsendAsBinary and use it in all browsers
                    if(!XMLHttpRequest.prototype.NEWsendAsBinary){
                        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.NEWsendAsBinary = function(datastr) {
                            function byteValue(x) {
                              return x.charCodeAt(0) & 0xff;
                            }
                            var ords = Array.prototype.map.call(datastr, byteValue);
                            var ui8a = new Uint8Array(ords);
                            this.send(ui8a.buffer);
                        }
                    }   
                    xhr.NEWsendAsBinary(builder+binary+builder2);
                };
                //read binary data
                reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
            }
            return false;
        }).bind ("dragover",function(evt) {
                evt.stopPropagation();
                evt.preventDefault();
                $(this).css({
                              border: '1px solid #ff0000'
                           });
                return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dropzone">
        <p>Drop Files Here</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer why this error occurs, but since Fx supports its sendAsBinary why not use it in it?

Also I made a fix related with fields file.name / file.fileName and changed this.open to xhr.open as Chrome and Fx seemed to interpret "this" there differently.

I'm pretty new to js, so I'm not sure about it, but this seems to work in Fx5, Fx7 and Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>cross browser drag and drop file upload example</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/libs/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// add the dataTransfer property for use with the native `drop` event
// to capture information about files dropped into the browser window
jQuery.event.props.push("dataTransfer");

$(function() {
    $('#dropzone').bind("drop",function(evnt) {
        evnt.stopPropagation();
        evnt.preventDefault();

        var data = evnt.dataTransfer;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
            var file = data.files[i];
            var fileName;
            if(file.name)
                    fileName = file.name;
                else
                    fileName = file.fileName; 

            var boundary = '------multipartformboundary' + (new Date).getTime();
            var dashdash = '--';
            var crlf     = '\r\n';

            // Build RFC2388 string
            var builder = '';
            var builder2 = '';

            builder += dashdash;
            builder += boundary;
            builder += crlf;

            // generate headers
            builder += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_file[]"';
            if (fileName) {
                builder += '; filename="' + fileName + '"';
            }
            builder += crlf;

            builder += 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream';
            builder += crlf;
            builder += crlf;

            //
            // binary data string in FileReader's onload (see below)
            //

            builder2 += crlf;

            //write boundary
            builder2 += dashdash;
            builder2 += boundary;
            builder2 += crlf;

            // mark end of the request
            builder2 += dashdash;
            builder2 += boundary;
            builder2 += dashdash;
            builder2 += crlf;


            // setup filereader: read file and send it
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(evt) {
                var binary = evt.target.result;

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "save.php", true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);

                //sendAsBinary: deprecated Mozilla only, define NEWsendAsBinary and use it in other browsers
                if(!XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary){
                    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.NEWsendAsBinary = function(datastr) {
                                    function byteValue(x) {
                                return x.charCodeAt(0) & 0xff;
                            }
                            var ords = Array.prototype.map.call(datastr, byteValue);
                            var ui8a = new Uint8Array(ords);
                            xhr.send(ui8a.buffer);
                        }
                        xhr.NEWsendAsBinary(builder+binary+builder2);
                    }
                    else {
                        xhr.sendAsBinary(builder+binary+builder2);
                    }
                };

                //read binary data
                reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
            }
            return false;
        }).bind ("dragover",function(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
            $(this).css({
            border: '1px solid #ff0000'
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dropzone">
        <p>Drop Files Here</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and ended up having to make sure the input element was multiselect enabled and that I was no longer using the obsolete attributes fileName and fileSize.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File

In my case I had to modify the following GWT file:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-fileapi/source/browse/trunk/gwt-fileapi/src/com/gwtpro/html5/fileapi/client/file/File.java?r=9